# How to generate Windows Store Appx Package From TFS Build

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Can any1 help me on generate *.appx package on every check-ins we do on Visual Studio. How to automate the process of generating the appx through TFS build. Please let me know what r the changes i need to do *.csproj so that appx package is created.

Answer (score 2):

```
msbuild WinStoreProject.csproj /p:AppxBundle=Always/p:Configuration=DEBUG /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:Platform=x86
```

Don't worry about the platform identifier. This approach will build a package that can support x64/x86/ARM. Look in your solution root under the AppPackages folder.

Enjoy!

Comment: and for windows 10, this also works, but you probably need to explicitly put `<AppxBundlePlatforms>ARM|x86|x64</AppxBundlePlatforms>` into your project, especially if you were using `<AppxBundlePlatforms>neutral</AppxBundlePlatforms>` (AnyCPU) in win8, since windows 10 store apps are compiled to .net native for each platform

Answer (score 0):

The `.csproj` file of Windows Store projects by default builds the AppPackage as well. You can try it out yourself by calling the following from the command line:

```
msbuild WinStoreApp.csproj
```

By default this will create the `AnyCPU` package. You can set the `Platform` property to create AppPackages for other platforms:

```
msbuild WinStoreApp.csproj /p:Platform=ARM
```

I suppose you will need Windows Server 2012 R2 to build Windows 8.1 applications an at least Windows Server 2012 to build Windows 8 applications. You will also need a working build environment. [Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) will certainly suffice; [Windows SDK for Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx) and [Microsoft Build Tools 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760) should be enough as well.

Comment: Hi Damir, I kept this command in Post-built event command line  msbuild MS.IT.CFIT.TaxHubClient /p:Platform=ARM or should i edit *.csproj file and set the msbuild to run this command.

Comment: @user145610 You don't need to put anything in the post build event. When you build the project from Visual Studio building and creating a package are separate actions. When building from command line (i.e. using `MSBuild`) you just need to pass the `.csproj` file to `MSBuild` and that's it. Open a Visual Studio command prompt to try it out. I'm not closely familiar with TFS build server but I suppose similarly to other build and integration servers, you just need to define the build action - in this case the MSBuild script you need to execute is your project.

Comment: HI Damir, I dont see any file with extension *.appx on build project from Visual Studio. I just see folder by name APPX but there is nuthing like APPX package file generated

Comment: @user145610 Running the above command from command line should create an `AppPackages` folder (if not already there), containing an `appx` file within a subfolder corresponding to the version, platform and configuration. Just like when you create the package from Visual Studio. Did `MsBuild` output any error when invoked, if it didn't work for you?

Comment: Hi,I edited by CSProJ with below code task                        <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
</Target>                                                           <target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="After build"></Message>
    <Exec Condition="'$(TeamBuildOutDir)'!='' " Command="&quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild.exe&quot; $(MSBuildProjectName).csproj /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=&quot;AnyCPU&quot;" ContinueOnError="false" /> </Target>Since i have given csproj, each msbuild task keeps invoking another msbuild -> goes into infite loop

Comment: @user145610 Why do you keep trying to modify the `csproj` file at all? There's no need for that. Don't do it.

Comment: without modifying the csproj , then how can perform build on Build Server. Build Server r maintained by different team.we dont have direct controll..I looking for solution with TFS build